# OpenCV Train Cascade create samples

Tags: opencv, object-detection, haar-classifier

I want a HAAR cascade training for detecting papers on a picture. So at the moment I have around 700 images of a random paper. That images only contain a paper, no background.

When I create a vec file with 'opencv_createsamples -img paper1.png -vec vec -num 10 -w 250 -h 177 -bg negatives' a vec file for one paper is created with 10 images. The width and height are arbitrary, but ratio matches the original paper sizes.

Now when I view the vec file, there are a lot of images where the paper is rotated or skewed. That is ok, but a lot of the paper is outside the image. When rotating a square, for example the top left or top right falls out of the image.

I do not want to recognize papers which are not completely visible on the picture. So how can I fix that?

The picture shows an image from the vec file to illustrate the issue. The content of the paper is removed in this image.
[image: paper in vec file with contents removed afterwards]

Comment: I have a set of positive and negative images. Is it possible to feed the positive images directly to the trainer? Thus skipping the create samples step. My positive images are already on different backgrounds and taken from different angles etc.

Answer (score 1):

opencv_createsamples also provides three parameters regarding rotation

```
-maxxangle <max_x_rotation_angle>
-maxyangle <max_y_rotation_angle>
-maxzangle <max_z_rotation_angle>
```

where all angles are given in radians.

According to the source of opencv_createsamples these parameters are initialized with default values

```
double maxxangle = 1.1;
double maxyangle = 1.1;
double maxzangle = 0.5;
```

so when left out, opencv_createsamples will still apply rotation to your samples.

You could now try to manually set the max angle to 0.

Comment: Thanks, that is an idea. But my detector also have to detect rotated papers etc. Does setting the maxangles to 0 also create a cascade which detects rotated/skewed papers?

Comment: No, because Haar like features are not rotation invariant.

You could either try to piecewise rotate your input image and apply the classifier to it, or go for another approach like an SVM.